# curl -O : Why it's not possible to download file specific directory?

Tags: directory, wget, curl, cd-command, download

The `man curl` entry for `curl -O` says:

> If you want the file saved in a different directory, make sure you 
>   change  cur‐
>                 rent working directory before you invoke curl with the -O, --remote-name flag!

Why it isn't possible to download the file to a specific directory and one has to do `cd /example` to download the file to a specific directory?

I know it's possible with `wget` this way:

```
wget -P /example https://example.com/file
```

But I do wonder why it seemingly isn't with `curl`.

Comment: [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). If you want to improve it with a feature it does not have, download its source code, study it, and patch it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because it is how `curl` is designed.

You can nonetheless achieve writing to output directory via shell redirection. Example:

```
$ curl http://example.com/file > /path/to/destination/file
```

Answer (score 7):

> Why it isn't possible to download the file to a specific directory and one has to do cd /example to download the file to a specific directory?

Because [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) has been designed that way. Since it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you could download its source code (perhaps with `git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git`) and study it. You'll find out that the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) system call is never used in it (it only appears in testing scripts coded in Perl).

If you don't want to explicitly `cd` in your shell before using `curl`, you might use something else, or patch the `curl` source code to add such an option (e.g. you could improve its code to accept some `--chdir` *dirname* program option, and then call the `chdir` [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call); in my opinion it is not worth the effort). Remember that each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has its *own* [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (inherited from its parent process). See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and read some Linux programming book (perhaps the old, but freely downloadable, [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf); also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html))

Of course you could use `curl` with absolute paths only (consider using [realpath(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) in your shell scripts, or [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) in your C programs, to get one)..

You could also and much more simply wrap `curl` in some [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) doing what you want; maybe some `incurl`  script as simple as:

```
#!/bin/sh
# this is your incurl shell script
cd "$1"
shift
exec curl "$@"
```

that you'll use e.g. with `incurl /tmp/ -O foo http://example.com/path/foobar.txt`  (to get some `/tmp/foo` from that URL).

You might also use the [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) library, perhaps from some [scripting language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) (like [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Python](http://python.org/), [Lua](http://lua.org/), [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), etc ...), or from a program written in a language implemented by compilers (Rust, Go, C++, C, Ocaml, ....). You could even find other HTTP client libraries (and HTTP server libraries too).

As to why the curl designers did not think of more features, bells and whistles, read about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). `curl` is a command line software which does one thing, but does it well. You'll compose or wrap it with other utilities (perhaps as simple as the `incurl` script above) to get more features. And sadly, `curl` does not make your morning coffee either.

<sup>PS. I am supposing you are using some POSIX or Unix-like OS such as Linux, MacOSX, AIX, ...</sup>